# Ember/Rails end-to-end testing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI app with a Rails back-end API. I am trying to set up end-to-end testing by configuring the Ember app test suite to send requests to a copy of the Rails API. My tests are working, but I am getting the following strange error frequently:

```
{}
Expected: true
Result: false

at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:4519:13
at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.exception (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:52144:7)
at onerrorDefault (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:42846:24)
at Object.exports.default.trigger (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:67064:11)
at Promise._onerror (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68030:22)
at publishRejection (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:66337:15)
```

This seems to occur whenever a request is made to the server. An example test script which would recreate this is below. This is a simple test which checks that if a user clicks a 'login' button without entering any email/password information they are not logged in. The test passes, but additionally I get the above error before the test passes. I think this is something to do with connecting to the Rails server, but have no idea how to investigate or fix it - I'd be very grateful for any help.

Many thanks.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from 'mercury-ember/tests/helpers/start-app';

module('Acceptance | login test', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    this.application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(this.application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Initial Login Test', function(assert)
{

  visit('/');

  andThen(function()
  {
      // Leaving identification and password fields blank
      click(".btn.login-submit");

      andThen(function()
      {
        equal(currentSession().get('user_email'), null, "User fails to login when identification and password fields left blank");
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the Network panel of Chrome or Firefox developer tools that the request is being made. At least with ember-qunit you can do this by getting ember-cli to run the tests within the browser rather than with Phantom.js/command-line.

That would help you figure out if it's hitting the Rails server at all (the URL could be incorrect or using the wrong port number?)

You may also want to see if there is code that needs to be torn down. Remember that in a test environment the same browser instance is used so all objects need to be torn down; timeouts/intervals need to be stopped; events need to be unbound, etc.

We had that issue a few times where in production there is no error with a utility that sent AJAX requests every 30 seconds, but in testing it was a problem because it bound itself to the window (outside of the iframe) so it kept making requests even after the tests were torn down.

Comment: Thanks. It is definitely hitting the Rails server - the requests are visible in the Chrome console and my tests are passing as expected, which wouldn't happen if it wasn't hitting the server. This weird error is _in addition_ to pass/fail messages about my tests.

Comment: Thanks but again I don't think it is due to teardown issues. The error appears when first running tests in a new incognito browser with caches disabled. As I understand it, code that should be torn down shouldn't affect the first run in a fresh browser instance.

Comment: The issue must be on the Rails side then, if you know which requests seem to cause the error you can add some print/logging statements to see what's happening, you can also add a debugger call (binding.pry) into the request. At this point it doesn't seem like an ember issue (but add some extra logging to be sure?)